# How to get User name from twitter

Tags: ios7, twitter, xcode5, twitter-oauth

In my app, I am adding Login with Twitter functionality [following this example](http://codegerms.com/login-with-twitter-example-with-ios-tutorial-using-oauth/).

Now, I want to get user name of logged in user.

Twitter suggest this URL call

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json
```

But how and where to put this URL?

Comment: Thanks for improving @Terence Eden.Can you please resolve the problem?

Comment: @TerenceEden , No I didn't try anything? I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: We're not here to do your work for you - see https://stackoverflow.com/tour - try something, and let us know what you're having problems with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you followed is first part of tutorial, In first part you get access token, Now follow the 2nd part of tutorial you will get all user information, Here is link
http://codegerms.com/get-user-info-data-twitter-api-example-ios-objective-c/

Comment: Its okay, Above answer will help others :)